# How to pass parameter to routed component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

On my current HTML page, there is "Preferences" option through which user will get navigated to preferences page. I want to pass 1 parameter from prev. component to navigated component.
account.component.html -

```
        <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/preferences']">
          <mat-icon ngClass="material-icons-outlined">home</mat-icon>
          <span>Preferences</span>
        </button>
```

I want to pass accountNumber from this html to preferences.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you. Either you can pass a variable or you can pass a value.

 To pass a variable you can use `[routerLink]="['/preferences', username]"`

```
<button mat-menu-item  [routerLink]="['/preferences', username]">
          <mat-icon ngClass="material-icons-outlined">home</mat-icon>
          <span>Preferences</span>
</button>
```

To Pass a value you can try => `routerLink="/preferences/nick"`

```
<button mat-menu-item routerLink="/preferences/nick">
          <mat-icon ngClass="material-icons-outlined">home</mat-icon>
          <span>Preferences</span>
</button>
```

In your `preferences` you have receive value or parameter like below=>

```
 username: string;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
 ngOnInit() {
    // snapshot way
    console.log('thing', this.route.snapshot.params.username);

    // observable way
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params.get('username'));
      this.username = params.get('username');
    }
```

**Note:** Please check the link of [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-parameters-fj5xwa?file=app%2Fuser.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your router is set up to receive parameters, and that `foo` holds the parameter you wish to pass:

```html
<button mat-menu-item routerLink="preferences/{{ foo }}">
```

Check your code that uses `@angular/router` to set up the router: where the path is set for `preferences`, update it to add the parameter. If the parameter were to be named `bar`:

```js
path: 'preferences/:bar'
```

On your `preferences` page, access the `bar` parameter:

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

 constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
 ) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.bar = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('bar');
}
```